# how to use MongoRepository to CRUD in a dynamic collection

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I dont want to use DBRef.
I want a database like this:
Different school has an own collection like

1. collection name "school1-students"
2. collection name "school2-students"
3. collection name "school3-students"......

Every collection is used to save students info.

As I know we can use @Document(collection = "school4") or use the MongoTemplate opertions to manage the collection name. However I want to use MongoRepository. I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public class PerSchoolStudentRepository {
    public static CrudRepository<Student, ObjectId> buildRepository(String school, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        MongoPersistentEntity<Student> persistentEntity = (MongoPersistentEntity<Student>) mongoOperations.getConverter().getMappingContext().getPersistentEntity(Student.class);
        MongoEntityInformation<Student, ObjectId> mongoEntityInformation = new MappingMongoEntityInformation<Student, ObjectId>(persistentEntity, school+"Students");
        return new SimpleMongoRepository<Student, ObjectId>(mongoEntityInformation, mongoOperations);
    }
}
```